# Why value of object's attribute returns zero after adding its pointer to a map in c++

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, dictionary, vector

So I have this:

```
//sons is an attribute of the object node that is a vector<Node*> that is initialized before
map<string,Node*> nodes;
string node_id = "node";
string son_id = "son";

Node *node = new Node(node_id, matrix, son_id, Prim);
cout << "Before " << node << endl;
cout << "Value of sons before map: " << node->sons[0] << endl;

nodes[node_id] = node;

cout << "After: " << nodes.find(node_id)->second << endl;
cout << "Value of sons after map: " << nodes.find(node_id)->second->sons[0];
```

I'm getting this output (with varying memory positions from execution to execution):

```
Before: 0x9dfdda8
Value of sons before map: 0xbff1a774 // consistant with memory position with created obj
After: 0x9dfdda8
Value of sons after map: 0
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?! I've been searching for the solution and trying to figure this out for 4 hours now...

Comment: What do you mean before and after map? Both outputs are from after adding node to the map...

Comment: What is `no` and `nos` and `root_id`?

Comment: You are mixing variable wildly in your example.

Comment: Can you post a complete, runnable program that demonstrates the problem? We've no way of knowing which of the errors in the code you've posted come from your real code, and which are copying errors.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: How can you say that both outputs are after map? Did you actually read the code?

Comment: @Everyone else: Typos corrected.

Comment: Not all: `cout << "Before " << no<< endl;`. Anyway, without a compilable example, it's going to be difficult to find the reason.

Comment: The code is huge at the moment... this code is in a xml parser that is being called in a lib that is implemented on top of OpenGL... So, not that easy to post a compilable example...

Comment: Though, if you really want to, search github for the repository 'laig'.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "After: " << nodes.find(root_id)->second << endl;
cout << "Value of sons after map: " << nos.find(root_id)->second->sons[0];
```

Why is the second line refering to `nos` and the first one `nodes`? Is it just a typo?

If those are really different objects, that might explain why you see inconsisten results

Comment: It's a typo. I have the code in PT, just translated it to EN while writing.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `node` to the `map` with the key `node_id` and then looking it up later with `root_id` and not even checking if it found one, so you're probably getting some undefined behaviour by accessing `end(nodes)`. You need to access the map with the same key to get the same object.

Also you appear to have some confusion with your variables, using `no` and `nos` when you are apparently needing to access either `node` or the map's variable.

Comment: I would say that in this case, node_id == root_id as the line After: 0x9dfdda8 gives the correct result. Most likely it is the nos vs node variable.